# How do I close a child form of a child form AND the child form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

For easy reference, I have a parent form (1), its' child form (2), and a child form of the child form (3).

I've searched and searched and all I am finding are ways to hide the 2nd form when the 3rd is opened. I am looking to go from the 3rd form straight to the 1st form by closing the 2nd and 3rd forms simultaneously.

Closing the 2nd form upon loading the 3rd is not an option because I also have a function on the 3rd form this.Close(); in order to take me to the 2nd form.

When I type the following:

```
 private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        frm2.Close();
    }
```

I get an error:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()"

Again, all I want is a command to be able to close two forms, form 2 and form 3, at once.

Edit:

My (wrong) code thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace frmGametime
{
public partial class frmX : Form
{
    public frmX()
    {
        private frmX frmTTT;
        public frmX()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frmTTT = new frmX();
            frmTTT.FormClosed += frmX_FormClosed;
        }

        void frmX_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmTTT.Show();
        }
    }

    private void frmX_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnNG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btn1.Text = "X";

        Random rng = new Random();
        int OppChoice = rng.Next(1, 9);

        if (OppChoice == 1)
        {
            if (this.btn1.Text == "_")
            {
                this.btn1.Text = "O";
            }
            else
            {
                OppChoice++;
            }
        }
        if (OppChoice == 2)
```

...

```
if (this.btn1.Text == "X" && this.btn2.Text == "X" && this.btn3.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn1.Text == "X" && this.btn4.Text == "X" && this.btn7.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn1.Text == "X" && this.btn5.Text == "X" && this.btn9.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn2.Text == "X" && this.btn5.Text == "X" && this.btn8.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn3.Text == "X" && this.btn6.Text == "X" && this.btn9.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn3.Text == "X" && this.btn5.Text == "X" && this.btn7.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn4.Text == "X" && this.btn5.Text == "X" && this.btn6.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }

        if (this.btn7.Text == "X" && this.btn8.Text == "X" && this.btn9.Text == "X")
        {
            this.lblWinner.Text = "X Wins!";
            this.lblWinner.Visible = true;
        }
    }

private void btnMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();    
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Have you ever read your error message? If you do, read one more time because it says exactly what you need. You need an object reference to call `.Close()` method. For example; `Form2 frm2 = new Form2(); frm2.Close();`

Comment: I try to, but it gets confusing sometimes, especially when I can't think of anything else it could possibly need. I appreciate the example, but when I implement it, it still only closes form 3.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the 3rd form's closed event in the second form. When the third form is closed the second form will see the event and execute it's handler. In the handler you can do this.Close();

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.FormClosed += form2_FormClosed;
    }

    void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

**Updated answer for your new example**

First of all it looks like you have a constructor within a constructor. I'm not even sure how that is compiling but by the looks of it your form `frmTTT` does not exist any longer after the last line `frmTTT.FormClosed += frmX_FormClosed;`

If you want your variable to stay alive the whole time you have to keep it in the root of the class `frmX:form`

Change

```
 public frmX()
{
    private frmX frmTTT;
    public frmX()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmTTT = new frmX();
        frmTTT.FormClosed += frmX_FormClosed;
    }

    void frmX_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTTT.Show();
    }
}
```

To

```
private frmX frmTTT;
    public frmX()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmTTT = new frmX();
        frmTTT.FormClosed += frmX_FormClosed;
    }

    void frmX_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTTT.Show();
    }
```

The outer

```
 public frmX()
{

}
```

Is not needed because you already have one inside. This is what is called a constructor and it initializes your object (creates it and makes it ready for use). In WinForms you can easily tell which is the form constructor by finding the line `InitializeComponent()` Go ahead and try that out. You shouldn't get that null reference error anymore

Comment: I keep trying to put this in several ways, and none of them are correct, so would you like for me to show you my code thus far so that you can point out what stupid things I'm doing?

Comment: Yes go ahead. I am just leaving work so I won't be home for another hour or so. I will check back in as soon as I get home.

Comment: Now when I click the button to go to frmX, the thing just quits responding.

Comment: which button are you talking about? Can you describe what's going on a little better?

Comment: I don't know if you've figured it out, but I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game. I have a form that allows the user to choose whether to be Xs or Os (Os is incomplete: finishing Xs first). Upon clicking the Xs button, which is the code you've been helping me work through, my form stops responding.

Comment: Yes I can see that. Why are you trying to close forms then exactly?  Paste your whole code here http://www.pastebucket.com/ and link back to it

Comment: Sorry, on the first form, I offer the user to play rock, paper, scissors, or tic, tic, toe. I am trying to make the forms more user-friendly so that the user can switch between games with as few clicks as possible. 

http://www.pastebucket.com/72810

Comment: Okay I'm going to look at your code. Take a look into Form.Hide() while I look at your code, that might be a better use in this scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66798/discussion-between-adrian-and-travis-j-land).